# How to redraw (change the backgroud color) a kml placemark by clicking on it?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openlayers-3

I have a page that displays square meshes from a KML.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUMHV.png)

https://saxrub.net/GeoPortail/500x500m.kml

The user can select / deselect meshes, the selection being materialized by the color of the mesh.
If he clicks on a red mesh, it turns green, and vice versa.

KML is added with

```
var KML3 = new ol.layer.Vector ({ 
  source: new ol.source.Vector ({ 
      url: kml_1x1km, 
         format: new ol.format.KML ({ 
             extractStyles: true, 
             showPointNames: showPointNames 
        }) 
    }) 
 }); 
 allLayers.push (KML3); 
 allLayerSwitcher.push ({ 
    layer: KML3, 
    config: { 
       title: kml_1x1km_title, 
       description: kml_1x1km_title, 
    } 
 })
```

The click on Placemarks is captured by:

```
 var displayFeatureInfo = function (pixel) { 
     var currentZoom = map.getView (). getZoom (); 
     var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel (pixel, function (feature, layer) { 
        return feature;
   }); 

 if (feature) { 
    var f = feature; 
    var att = feature.getProperties (); 
    styleUrl = att.styleUrl.split ("#"); 
    mesh=att.description.split = ( "~"); 
    if (styleUrl [1] == "Red_red") 
        { 
             att.styleUrl = "# Jaune_Vert"; 
             feature.style = eval (mesh [3]). getStyle ("#Yellow_Green",   {}) 
         } 
    else 
         { 
               att.styleUrl = "# Rouge_Rouge"; 
               feature.style = eval (mesh [3]). getStyleFunction ("# Red_Red", {}) 
      `   } 
 eval (mesh [3]) redraw (). 
 this.unselect (feature); 
 return 1; 
 } else { 
 return 0; 
 } 
};
```

With the OpenLayer 2 of the API I was doing

```
  if (f) { 

  mesh=f.attributes.description.split = ( "~"); 

  if (f.attributes.styleUrl == "# Red_Red") 
     { 
         f.attributes.styleUrl = "# Jaune_Vert"; 
         f.style = eval (mesh [3]). protocol.format.getStyle ("#Yellow_Yellow", {}) 
     } 
   else 
     { 
         f.attributes.styleUrl = "# Rouge_Rouge"; 
         f.style = eval (mesh [3]). protocol.format.getStyle ("# Red_red", {}) 
     } 
eval (mesh [3]) redraw (). 
 this.unselect (f); 
 }
```

but I can not find the equivalent of the redraw function in V4.

An idea ?

Comment: Could you provide a well-formatted source code? Right now, it's unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

The way you currently set the style on the selected feature will do nothing, because `ol/Feature` has no `style` property. You have to use the `setStyle()` setter function:

```
feature.setStyle(yourStyle);
```

The renderer will get notified of this change, so you don't need to redraw anything manually after calling `setStyle()` on a feature.

Comment: Thank you
The track is good.
In KML, there are two styles, a Red and a Green.
Is it possible to retrieve them to apply them with setStyle?

Comment: With 
feature.setStyle(new ol.style.Style({
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({color: 'rgba(0,170,00,1)'}),
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({color: 'rgba(170,255,0,0.5)'})
    }));
it's work fine !
But now, when I first click, I get my style named KML file (Red or Green).
After the setStyle, how do I know which style is applied if the user clicks on the mesh because in this case, I always get the named style of KML?